# How do I utilize the item_sort_key feature of simplejson?

Tags: python, sorting, simplejson

Consider the following json snippet:

```
[
    {
        "starts_at": "2015-09-14 01:07:52",
        "created_at": "2015-09-15 00:03:19",
        "guid": "335eccaa689c480a91bff731712250d9"
    },
    {
        "guid": "13f0e832fd0404170ae7501c288d6708",
        "created_at": "2015-09-16 00:03:21",
        "starts_at": "2015-09-15 00:03:19"
    }
]
```

that I need to be able to sort by "guid", such that in this example, I should get this:

```
[
    {
        "guid": "13f0e832fd0404170ae7501c288d6708",
        "created_at": "2015-09-16 00:03:21",
        "starts_at": "2015-09-15 00:03:19"
    },
    {
        "starts_at": "2015-09-14 01:07:52",
        "created_at": "2015-09-15 00:03:19",
        "guid": "335eccaa689c480a91bff731712250d9"
    }
]
```

I did this using `jq 'sort_by(.guid)'`, but I need to do it using python. I know this can be done by setting `item_sort_key` to "guid", but I cannot find a single example of how to do this. Can anyone help me out please?